# How can I exclude specific links from the base url?

Tags: jquery

On my Website I need to use a base url:

```
<base href="http://www.mypage.com" />
```

I have some links that are connected to jquery functions and look for example like this:

```
<a href="#top" class="link-to-top"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
```

The problem is now that with the base url my "go to top button" doesn't link to the top of the page, instead it links to http://www.mypage.com/#top. But this is wrong.

So is it possible to exclude the base url for specific href links?

---

To be more specific:

I am using a scrolling navigation like this http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

Comment: *"my functions do not work"*   What functions? None are shown. We can't help debug code we can't see

Comment: *Written in front* means?

Comment: @John R I updated my question to be more specific

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question

Comment: Please put actual code in question itself. Questions should be self contained. That link doesn't show us the code you are using

Comment: the code is very long unfortunately to post it here. Maybe you can answer my basic question: is it in general possible for some href links to ignore the base path?

Comment: Sure ... if we knew what the code was that was causing a problem